# Как посчитать модуль числа в CSS

Tags: css

могу ли я посчитать модуль через CSS?
У меня есть такое выражение **y = -34 * abs(x - 0.5) + 17** (x изменяется от 0 до 1)

Вот график такой функции, можно посмотреть: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4zdruwvikn?lang=ru
Я бы хотел это вычислить в CSS, это возможно?

```js
const blockNode = document.querySelector('.block');

const y = blockNode.computedStyleMap().get('transform')[0].y;

document.write(`${y.value}${y.unit}`);
```

```css
.block {
  --x: 0;
  --y: calc(1px + 2px);
  transform: translate(0px, var(--y));
  
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
</div>
```

Comment: `abs()` обязателен?

Comment: @De.Minov мне нужно посчитать модуль числа, можно и простые операции делать. Я смотрел, abs функцию в CSS только планируют ввести. Пробовал в хроме, не работает https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/abs()

Comment: Вот да, на чистом CSS это сложновато сделать, если есть возможность, то лучше использовать препроцессоры

Comment: @De.Minov ну, а это уже я лучше буду делать в JS. Я хотел написать зависимость в CSS, а через JS я просто изменял бы переменную x. Буду ждать, когда введут функцию abs, да и вообще весь этот CSS4
https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-4/#math

Comment: @De.Minov сделал :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я сделал: оказывается, функция max в CSS работает, [can i use](https://caniuse.com/?search=CSS%20math%20functions%20min()%2C%20max()%20and%20clamp())
Зачем я использовал max - чтобы найти модуль числа, необходимо сравнить
само число и его [аддитивную инверсию](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_inverse)(если проще -> умноженное на -1) и выбрать большее

```js
const blockNode = document.querySelector('.block');

const y = blockNode.computedStyleMap().get('transform')[0].y
document.write(`${y.value}${y.unit}`);
```

```css
@property {}

.block {
  --x: 0.5;
  --xPx: var(--x) * 1px;
  --leftAbsX: calc( 1 * (var(--xPx) - 0.5px) );
  --rightAbsX: calc( -1 * (var(--xPx) - 0.5px) );
  --abs: max( var(--leftAbsX), var(--rightAbsX) );
  --y: calc(-1 * 34 * var(--abs) + 17px);
  transform: translate(0px, var(--y));
  
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
</div>
```

Зачем это всё делалось, пример с анимацией:

```js
const blockNode = document.querySelector('.block');
const infoNode = document.querySelector('.info');

requestAnimationFrame(anim);

function anim(time) {
  const angle = blockNode.computedStyleMap().get('transform')[0].angle;
  infoNode.textContent = `${Math.round(angle.value)}${angle.unit}`;
  requestAnimationFrame(anim);
}
```

```css
@property --x {
  syntax: '<number>';
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 0;
}

.block {
  --x: 0;
  --leftAbsX: calc( 1 * (var(--x) - 0.5) );
  --rightAbsX: calc( -1 * (var(--x) - 0.5) );
  --abs: max( var(--leftAbsX), var(--rightAbsX) );
  --deg: 17deg;
  --rotate: calc(-2 * var(--deg) * var(--abs) + var(--deg));
  
  transform: rotate(var(--rotate));
  animation: anim 2s linear infinite alternate-reverse;
  
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    --x: 0;
    background-color: red;
  }
  100% {
    --x: 1;
    background-color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="info"></div>
```

Comment: Интересное решение (+)