# CSS Как с помощью операций min и max сделать сравнение ===

Tags: css, логика

Я поставил перед собой задачу: хочу в CSS делать сравнения типа ===
У меня есть переменная `percent` от 0 до 1.
Я хочу создать переменную `opacity`, которая:
opacity = 1, если percent === 0
opacity = 0, если percent !== 0

Это правило нужно написать один выражением математическим, чтобы в CSS работало оно

Я уже научился делать [вычисление модуля числа в CSS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1385894/331312)
Эту задачу нужно как-то решить с помощью функций min, max, abs (их в CSS я могу применить).
Ещё можно делать умножение, деление, складывать, вычитать.

Приложу пример кода, вот `--opacity: max(var(--percent), 1);`  тут должно быть само вычисление

```css
.card {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  --percent: 0;
  --opacity: max(var(--percent), 1);
  opacity: var(--opacity);
}
```

```html
<div class="card"></div>
```

Comment: По сути тебе нужна [ceil](https://css-tricks.com/using-absolute-value-sign-rounding-and-modulo-in-css-today/#aa-round-as-well-as-ceil-and-floor) функция

Comment: @Grundy пошёл читать и смотреть какая там поддержка

Comment: Все функции до сих пор были непрерывные. По некоторым причинам из непрерывных функций можно составлять только непрерывные. А вы просите построить функцию с разрывом. Нужно что ещё.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy что такое непрерывные?

Comment: Которые можно нарисовать карандашом в одну линию.

Comment: Вы можете сделать такую подставу: *(1 - percent) * (1 - percent) * ... * (1 - percent)*. Чем больше множителей, тем больше эта непрерывная функция будет похожа на ту что вам нужна.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я удивлён, но благодаря [Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy), который предоставил ссылку на [реализацию округления](https://css-tricks.com/using-absolute-value-sign-rounding-and-modulo-in-css-today/#aa-round-as-well-as-ceil-and-floor) и не только, у меня получилось решить эту задачу.

В статье описывалось, что можно округлить CSS переменную как ceil, если сделать так:

```css
@property --ceil {
  syntax: '<integer>';
  initial-value: 0;
  inherits: false /* or true depending on context */
}

.my-elem {
  --ceil: calc(var(--a) + 0.5)
}
```

То есть нужно указать переменной, что она integer, прибавить ей 0.5 и это будет работать как ceil округление. Но по факту у меня это не работало. Хотя может это баги хрома? Я просто прибавил не 0.5, а 0.49 и у меня всё начало работать

Можно это проверить, если в этом примере в браузере изменять CSS переменную percent, всё работает.

opacity = 1, если percent === 0
opacity = 0, если percent !== 0

```css
@property --ceil {
  syntax: '<integer>';
  initial-value: 0;
  inherits: false;
}

.card {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  --percent: 0.1;
  --ceil: calc(var(--percent) + 0.499);
  --opacity: var(--ceil);
  opacity: var(--opacity);
}
```

```html
<div class="card"></div>
```

Comment: Решение хорошее, но не работает на Firefox, посмотрите компилябельность на MDN или на CanIUse

Comment: @ΝNL993 а не нужон нам этот ваш фаерфукс и safari. Браузеры потом подтянутся. Я изучаю новые возможности CSS. чем больше людей будет использовать код неподдерживаемый в других браузерах, тем активнее браузеры начнут внедрять в свои браузеры те вещи, которые не были у них включены. Кому-то приходится всё-таки быть исследователем в этом приключении в недра браузера

Comment: `а не нужон нам этот ваш фаерфукс и safari.` - По данным статистики собранной GNOME, Firefox составляет 70 и более процентов (на линукс). `чем больше людей будет ...`, согласен, но проблема в том, что мало кто использует `@property`, плюс к тому у него [проблема при использовании переменных как `initial-value`](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1490285) (считаю это большим недостатком).

Comment: @ΝNL993 да, эти проблемы, потому что разрабы, которые разрабатывают CSS не делают то, что мало применяют. И чтобы разрабы начали норм работать, нужно, чтобы это активнее применялось

Comment: Ну вообще-то, это никак не изменить, функции в CSS сами по себе имеют отдельный тип данных (каждая функция - новый тип), то есть как бы не использовали @property, это проблема останется как есть, потому что тогда нужно будет менять стандарты, а этого никто не будет делать.

Comment: @ΝNL993 конечно будет, это всё разрабатывают, ты что. Сейчас очень много чего разрабатывается

Answer (score 0):

В питоне:

```py
opacity = int(not(percent))
```

Comment: int, not это уже дополнительные операции, которые я не говорил применять

Comment: а min, max и abs это не дополнительные операции?

Comment: min, max, abs, +, -, *, / - это те операции, которые я разрешил использовать

Comment: @Эникейщик причём тут Python?

Comment: @ΝNL993 если посмотрите историю редактирования вопроса, то узнаете при чем